# placeCaretAtEnd seemingly not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have a content editable DIV containing a P tag with text in it and am using placeCaretAtEnd to position the caret at the end of the content inside the P tag. This seems to work well for every browser with the exception of Firefox (v32.0.3). On that, the caret just seemingly disappears.

From what I can tell, the placeCaretAtEnd JS function is supposedly fully compatible with Firefox. Any idea why this isn't working in this instance?

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/0ktff3zj/1/

```
<input id=button type=button value="Caret to end">
<div contenteditable=true>
    <p id="paragraph">Sample text. Sample text.</p>
</div>

<script>
$('#button').bind('click', function() {
    placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById('paragraph'))
});

function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
        && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this issue by placing the cursor in the contenteditable div and then using the placeCaratAtEnd function to move it.

First I gave the div an id so there would be no mix ups.

```
$('#button').bind('click', function() {
    $('div#id').focus();
    placeCaretAtEnd(document.getElementById('paragraph'))
});
```

I searched forever and while I know this is a bit on the hackish side, it is a solution.